# How to change the terminal user name on macOS

Tags: terminal

I am a new Mac user and when I set up my account I did not put in the correct user name to log in to my work system.

I have copied and recreated the user profile with the name I want in the terminal but nothing has changed.

All the information in the terminal still shows the old user name and will not allow me to login since my user name does not match the work user name and password.

I am trying to learn and will need 3rd grade assistance with this as I am not very good with this, but wanting to learn.

Simply put, if my user name is

```
abcde1234@Christophers-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

and I want to change it to

```
abcde@Christophers-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

how would I change the terminal to show `abcde` with the `1234` removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you want to customize is called the *prompt*. How you can change it depends on which shell you use but I assume you use Zsh.

You can type `echo "$PS1"` to see how your existing prompt is defined.

Create the file `~/.zshrc` if it does not exist already and add the line `PROMPT='abcde@%m %1~ %# '`.

- Replace `abcde` with your user name
- `%m` is your hostname
- `%1~` is your current working directory
- `%#` prints a ‘#’ if the shell is running with root privileges or ‘%’ if not

For the full list of prompt expansion, see [zshmisc(1)](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html).

Comment: Wow, so still had to look up how to create the file, but got it! Thank you for the help worked flawlessly. Tried to upvote but haven't reached that level yet.

Answer (score 2):

I combined [this information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645174/97255) with this other part.

In `~/.zshrc`, you enter this line of code:

```
export PS1="whatever name"
```

then save and exit and restart the terminal.

This will change the name in the terminal.

Comment: Please don't add thanks as it is confusing, as it isn't clear who you are thanking (besides not being required... just vote instead). Presumeably you are referring to Devon's answer (to which I've suggested linking to, make your answer clearer)?